# Firebase - Handle token expiry case

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase authentication inside my application. Firebase SDK automatically refreshes the token as needed, however how would one go about handling a scenario where the token expires before the refresh was able to be completed.

I considered using **OnIDTokenChanged** or **OnAuthStateChanged**, however I can't seem to understand how these functions would catch and handle these scenarios. Could anyone suggest a method to handle this scenario? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Firebase SDK can't refresh the token, then the user is considered signed out, and your auth state observer will show that no user is signed in. It's up to you to respond to this change in state by asking the user to sign in again.

Comment: Hello, so just to understand, if the token can't be refreshed, the user is signed out, then the OnAuthStateChanged listener is fired, and I can handle the code to reauthenticate the user again in there? Thanks.

Comment: Also just to something to add. Are you saying if Firebase can't refresh the token, the user will automatically be set to signed out?

Comment: There is no guarantee that you can immediately sign in the user in the callback.  You should ask them to sign in again as if they were never signed in to begin with. The user is either fully signed in or fully signed out.  There is no intermediate state.

Comment: Ok thanks. So when the **OnAuthStateChanges** Callback gets ran, the user is always either signed out or signed in, and  if signed out, you should ask them to sign in like they did at the start, correct?

Comment: That's what I'm saying.